# Use SQLITE/Room table columns as function params

Tags: sqlite, date, triggers, android-sqlite, android-room

So I came across the following sides:

[sqlite dates](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-date-function/)

[sqlite dates functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Which explains how the date function can be used in SQLITE (which is the equilvanet to dateadd in sql)

So I came to an idea, to store the date function parameters (interval, value) in the table which I will want to use in the trigger.
This kinda looks like this:

```
database.execSQL(
"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_afMR " +
"AFTER INSERT ON Table1 " +
"BEGIN  " +
"UPDATE Table2 SET nextRepeatDate = date(nextRepeatDate,+interval repeatmentType)" +
"WHERE NEW.idTable2=Table2.idTable; " +
"END;");
```

In this case `interval` (= 1,2,..) and `repeatmentType`(DAY,MONTH,YEAR) are parameters in `Table2`, however the issue is that sqlite does not recognize the table2 columns as params:
`'(', ')', '.', BETWEEN or IN expected, got 'repeatmentType'`

Is it even possible to use table columns in sqlite as params? Or is this kind of function only possible in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument of the function `date()` is a string and you can construct it by concatenating `interval` and `repeatmentType`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tr_afMR 
AFTER INSERT ON Table1 
BEGIN  
  UPDATE Table2 
  SET nextRepeatDate = date(nextRepeatDate, interval || ' ' || repeatmentType)
  WHERE idTable = NEW.idTable2; 
END;
```

The expression `interval || ' ' || repeatmentType` will be evaluated to something like `'3 day'`. There is no need for the `+` sign.

Comment: it worked perfect thanks. in this case, would it be possible to multyply the interval value? Like : interval *7 if repeatmentType is WEEK as date does not support "week " only other datetypes like day, month, etc..

Comment: @FunnyMoments no WEEK is not supported. What you can do is: `date(nextRepeatDate, (7*interval) || ' ' || repeatmentType)` .